# How do you parse basic (short/compact) ISO:8601 string with Joda?

Tags: timezone-offset, datetime-parsing, js-joda

I have a time string, which looks like this: `20170822T194135+00`. This is called basic ISO:8601 format, if I understood correctly.

When I try to parse it using `ZonedDateTime`, it throws exception, complaining that it can't parse it.

SO, how do I convert this string to a valid Joda datetime object?

Do I need to build manual "format" to parse it (this would be silly, considering it's a standard format)?

---

Desperately, I've actually tried to implement custom format:

```ts
const time = ZonedDateTime.parse(timeString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(`yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ`));
```

But, it throws error on column `15`. Looks like it fails to parse the timezone. Is my implementation correct? How do I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could do it using the pattern `x` as described in the [docs](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/esdoc/class/src/format/DateTimeFormatter.js~DateTimeFormatter.html#static-method-ofPattern) (this pattern accepts offsets like `+00`).

Then I parsed directly to a `ZonedDateTime`:

```ts
const formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssx");

const time = ZonedDateTime.parse("20170822T194135+00", formatter);
```

The resulting `time` variable has the value equivalent to `2017-08-22T19:41:35Z`.

The built-in formatters (such as `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`) can't parse this format, so the only way seems to be creating a formatter.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the "x" specifier was exactly what I was missing.